# PHP Extract SSL certificate information from IP

Tags: php, ssl

I need to extract SSL certificate information from an IP address, not from a domain name. Let's take www.adidas.com, just for example. This domain name is resolving to 2.21.90.7 IP address. Code below successfully extracting certificate information, if stream_socket_client conecting to domain name, but stream_socket_client even do not creating without any error, if connection made to IP address, why?

```
$addr = '2.21.90.7';
//$addr = 'www.adidas.ru';

$get = stream_context_create(array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => TRUE)));
$read = stream_socket_client("ssl://".$addr.":443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
var_dump($get);
var_dump($read);
var_dump($errno);
var_dump($errstr);
$cert = stream_context_get_params($read);
var_dump($cert);
$certinfo = openssl_x509_parse($cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);
var_dump($certinfo);
```

PS: If I opening https://2.21.90.7/ in my Chrome Browser, It shows me, that certificate is issued to www.adidas.com, as expected.

Comment: Do you have `$errno` populated?

Comment: No, $errno = false, problem is solved after disabling peer and peer_name verifying in SSL context: 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false,

Comment: Many websites nowadays requires SNI over HTTPS so you need to connect with a name, not an IP. Otherwise you will get connection problems or not retrieve the correct certificate. Remember that an IP address could correspond to many names, so if you connect just with the name how is the server suppose to understand which website you really want?

Comment: In my case, I'm exactly know, that IP has only one certificate, so I've disabled SNI in SSL context, 'SNI_enabled' => false,